# react I want to change the color with the value passed by props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using react and typescript.
I want to change the color with the value passed by props.
In props, the string type primary, secondary, or brand will be passed.
When the primary comes in, I want to apply "blue" to the background, "green" to the secondary, and "yellow" to the brand.

```
type Props = {
  backgroundColor: 'primary' | 'secondaｒｙ' | 'brand';
  size?: 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
};


export const Button: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ backgroundColor, size, children }) => {
    return (
      <Box colorScheme={backgroundColor} size={size}>
        {children}
      </Box>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `Box` component takes a colour as its `colorScheme` prop, simply define a mapping from the `backgroundColor` to the colour you want to apply.

```
const COLORS: Record<Props['backgroundColor'], string> = {
    primary: "blue",
    secondary: "green",
    brand: "yellow"
};

export const Button: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ backgroundColor, size, children }) => {
    return (
      <Box colorScheme={COLORS[backgroundColor]} size={size}>
        {children}
      </Box>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: <Props['backgroundColor'], string>
↑Is this writing style called generics?